# Windows 8 black screen after waking from sleep

Tags: windows-8, sleep, wake-up

## Detailed

The problem, when I trying to "awake" PC from sleep or hibernate (which running OS Windows 8 X64 Pro) getting black screen (Actually sometimes it awakes normally. But I can't figure out pattern when it doesn't display after awake). But I know that, all processes are running in background, just display problem.

## My idea

I thinks it's related with my VGA cards' drivers. Here is y PC's configuration

http://valid.canardpc.com/show_oc.php?id=2532681

I have 2 VGA Adapters

[image]

When I installed system, on first start I downloaded and installed latest drivers for Nvidia. I tried to uninstall this drivers - same problem.

What it can be related with? How to fix this problem

Comment: Sounds like a driver conflict to me.  You said you tried the latest NVIDIA drivers, but did you do the same for the Intel adapter?  It looks like both NVIDIA and Intel have drivers certified for Windows 8:  
NVIDIA: [http://www.geforce.com/drivers/results/50007](http://www.geforce.com/drivers/results/50007) 
Intel: [Intel Drivers](http://downloadcenter.intel.com/Detail_Desc.aspx?agr=Y&DwnldID=22020&lang=eng&OSVersion=Windows%208*&DownloadType=%0A%09%09%09%09%09%09%09Drivers%0A%09%09%09%09%09%09)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I guess this is a little late but try the new NVidia/intel drivers that are now WHQL certified.

Also if that does not fix it, it sounds like a possible SSD problem. Are you running an SSD? if so, try updating your firmware.